# How to get something inside wrapper 100% browser width

Tags: html, css, wrapper, codepen

This is my problem,

I have a website with some content, and i want the header to be 100% width of the browser, and some content that's wrapped inside wrapper to make it about.. 50% of the browser width.

Then we have something like this:
[image: img1]
But, we're adding a menu aswell. This is done with UL, and we cant just add the menu (i think), because the content of the menu is going to be in the wrapper.  So it looks like this:
[image: img2]

**What have i tried?**
I've given the element header/menu this css:

```
padding-left: 3000px;
margin-left: -3000px;
padding-right: 3000px;
margin-right: -3000px;
```

I also added overflow-x:hidden; on the body element so they cant scroll x wise. But on their phones, they can. So this makes everything "unresponsive"

HTML:

```
<html>
<title>Rocket League Prices - Home</title>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <a href="/index.php">
      <div class="header-1">
         Rocket League Prices
      </div>
    </a>   
 </header>
     <ul class="nav-top">
<li class="nav-top"><a href="/index.php" title="HOME" class="nav-top">
    <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" ></i><br><span     class="meny-text">Home</span></a></li>

<li class="nav-top"><a href="/pc.php" title="PC PRICE LIST" class="nav-top">
    <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><span class="meny-text">PC list</span></a></li>

<li class="nav-top"><a href="/ps4.php" title="PS4 PRICE LIST" class="nav-top">
    <i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><span class="meny-text">PS4 list</span></a></li>

        <li class="nav-top"><a href="/certified.php" title="CERTIFIED LIST" class="nav-top">
    <i class="fa fa-certificate" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><span class="meny-text">Certified list</span></a></li>

    <li class="nav-top" style="float:right;!important" >
            <a href="#" class="nav-top meny-text" data-toggle="modal" data-    target="#modal-staff">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <br>Staff</a></li>

</ul>
                  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-staff" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
```

CSS:

```
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  header{
padding: 20px;
background-color: #1798e5;
color: black;
padding-left: 3000px;
margin-left: -3000px;
padding-right: 3000px;
margin-right: -3000px;

}
ul.nav-top {
background-color: white;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 0 auto;
float:left;
color: #34495e;
display:table-row;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
margin-bottom: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 3000px;
margin-left: -3000px;
padding-right: 3000px;
margin-right: -3000px;
}
li a.nav-top{
color: #34495e;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 20px 20px;
}
li a.nav-top:hover{
background-color: #f1f2f3;
color: #1798e5;
}
li.nav-top {
text-decoration: none;
float: left;
}
.wrapper{
max-width: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

CODEPEN: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdLpzM

Comment: and you are positive you cant place the nave outside the wrapper, right?

Comment: The menu? Yes, but then the content wont stay in the wrappers width. @JSelsere

Comment: Sorry, what you want is a little unclear to me, can you state what should the page end up looking like in a sentence?

Comment: Its going to have 1 menu, the menu has 100% browser height. Its also going to have content with 10px space between eachother. Basically, the content of the menu is going to be inside the wrappers width, but still the background color should have 100% width @JSelser

Comment: I cant catch what you exactly want to get. Can you add an image (paint) showing what you are looking for please? I will return you it corrected if i can see what you want

Comment: you dont add full html code on codepen and here. and those padding and margin and same class you use for ul, li ,a dosen't make any sense. 
you can check this [ https://jsfiddle.net/jwc124x6/1/ ] as a example   and its responsive . Please Check those changes. I suggest you to learn html css  [ http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp ] and then you can move to bootstrap . Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your html has to change a bit.

```html
<html>
<title>Rocket League Prices - Home</title>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="/index.php">
        <div class="header-1">
          Rocket League Prices
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="column">
    <ul class="nav-top ">
      <li class="nav-top">
        <a href="/index.php" title="HOME" class="nav-top">
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <br><span class="meny-text">Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-top">
        <a href="/pc.php" title="PC PRICE LIST" class="nav-top">
          <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <br><span class="meny-text">PC list</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-top">
        <a href="/ps4.php" title="PS4 PRICE LIST" class="nav-top">
          <i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <br><span class="meny-text">PS4 list</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-top">
        <a href="/certified.php" title="CERTIFIED LIST" class="nav-top">
          <i class="fa fa-certificate" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <br><span class="meny-text">Certified list</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-top" style="float:right;!important">
        <a href="#" class="nav-top meny-text" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-staff">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <br>Staff</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

and your css

```css
.column {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
header {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: #1798e5;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
ul.nav-top {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  color: #34495e;
  display: table-row;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li a.nav-top {
  color: #34495e;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}
li a.nav-top:hover {
  background-color: #f1f2f3;
  color: #1798e5;
}
li.nav-top {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: For further explanation: What you are trying to do, expanding the header out of it´s box with minus margins is only useful if you have fixed widths but it is still a rather complicated and unusual way to do it.

Comment: A better solution would be the example above. If you still want to wrap everything in one wrapper and only want the header background ( like in your example in your codepen script) then you can fake that with an empty layout div outside the wrapper that is positioned absolute, with that blue background-color, width 100% and height of the header.